# Define a function, call it ‘CHECK’ in scheme

Tags: function, scheme, lisp

how to write this in scheme?

Define a function, call it ‘CHECK’ that takes an integer as its first argument, a list of integers
as its second argument and returns the count of how many times the first argument appears in the second

Comment: If you want to show your non-working code, don't post it as an answer. Rather, edit your question and put the code in there.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a variation of what is usually called `count':

```
(define (check num ls) (count (lambda (val) (= val num)) ls))
(check 2 '(2 3 4 2)) ; => 2
```